# Looking for an example of using code with Apache License Version 2.0

Tags: licensing, open-source, apache-license

I know there are a lot of Q/As in legalese or plain English. I am wondering if anyone could provide a real life example of the text that needs to be included with the distribution of software using code with Apache License Version 2.0.

For example, if an app uses [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/), a Java library with Apache License Version 2.0, what is the text regarding this license needed to be included in its distribution?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [boilerplate notice for the Apache License is](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html#apply):

> Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you
>   may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may
>   obtain a copy of the License at
>
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied. See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and limitations under the License.

There is also the complete Apache License v2 available in [HTML](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) and [TXT](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt) formats.

---

If you are distributing a source code for a project, you should place the complete license in a text file called LICENSE at the root of the project. If you need a NOTICE file (projects run by the Apache Software Foundation require one), it goes at the same level.

If you are distributing a binary for a project and are providing a JAR or a tarball, then the LICENSE (and NOTICE) files must be at the top level. That is, when you uncompress the file, you should see a LICENSE (and NOTICE) file in the target.

If you are distribute a single file (such as a Gist on GitHub), then [you are probably OK with putting the boilerplate notice at the top of the file](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2365/is-it-possible-to-include-a-shorter-form-of-a-license-if-the-license-would-be-lo).

If you are using Apache License v2 licensed software in your project, you need to include the LICENSE and NOTICE files for that library. The way I usually do this is that I have a `lib` directory in the root of my project. I would extract the library distribution into a subdirectory of the lib directory. Assuming that the author packaged their application properly, it will contain the appropriate license files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, Thomas.  It looks like my question is not very clear. Your last paragraph is the answer that I was looking for.   I have an Android library using multiple Apache License v2 licensed library jars.  I added a sub-directory to directory lib with a text file, but I could not find anything related to the newly added text file in the library's aar file. What should I do in this case?  The aar file will be used by multiple Android apps.